# Proof of the limit

Tags: calculus, limits

When $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = a$, prove $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{nx_1 + (n-1)x_2 + \cdots + 2x_{n-1} + x_n}{n^2} = \frac{a}{2}.$$

Comment: First try to show that the limit exists (via showing it bounded) then try using Cesaro-Stolz Theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem

Comment: Thanks to r9m and kmitov, I understand how to prove it with Cesaro-Stolz theorem now.  Is it also possible to prove simply using the epsilon-delta?  This problem appeared in the introductory textbook after the epsilon-delta chapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $y_n=nx_1+(n-1)x_2+\ldots+2x_{n-1}+x_n$, then  $y_{n+1}=(n+1)x_1+nx_2+(n-1)x_3+\ldots+2x_{n}+x_{n+1}$ and 
$y_{n+1}-y_n=x_1+x_2+x_3+\ldots+x_n+x_{n+1}$.

$(n+1)^2-n^2=n(2+1/n)$.

and 
$\frac{y_{n+1}-y_n}{(n+1)^2-n^2}-\frac{1}{2+1/n}\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3+\ldots+x_n+x_{n+1}}{n+1}\frac{n+1}{n} \to \frac{1}{2}.a.1=\frac{a}{2}.$

The Stolz theorem completes the proof.

Comment: Wow, I did not know that theorem.  Thank you very much!